Full Backup of Metadata for PieCloudDB Data Warehouse
I am using PieCloudDB and I would like to know how to full backup the metadata of PieCloudDB data warehouse. I've been exploring the documentation but I'm still unsure about the best practices. Any guidance, scripts, or tools that can help this process would be greatly appreciated.

The metadata layer of PieCloudDB Database is built on FoundationDB, the backup requires the tools provided by FoundationDB.
The process of full backup is as follows:
1.Use date for backup tag naming. FoundationDB backup supports the tag function to facilitate users to find backup files.
tag_name=$(date +%s)

2.Manually back up the Tenant directory on FoundationDB.
fdbcli --exec "getrange \xff\xff/management/tenant_map \xff\xff/management/ tenant_map\xff 100" > /[your_file_system_path] 

--Tenant Map Example Response: 
Range limited to 100 keys 
`\xff\xff/management/tenant_map/marco01' is `{"id":0,"prefix":"\\u0000\\u0000\ \u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000"}' `\xff\xff/management/tenant_map/marco02' is `{"id":1,"prefix":"\\u0000\\u0000\ \u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0001"}'

3.Start full backup.
fdbbackup start -t ${tag_name} -d "file://[your_path]

4.Check backup tasks.
fdbbackup status -t ${tag_name} 

--Example Response: 
The previous backup on tag `1693926803' at file:///fdb/backupdata2/ backup-2023-09-05-23-13-23.668523 completed at version 15924894672514. 
BackupUID: 49736722c1ec9a11a13a669a1b2bcf73 
BackupURL: file:///fdb/backupdata2/backup-2023-09-05-23-13-23.668523

5.Check the status of the backup task. If the restorable field flag is "True", the full backup has been completed.
fdbbackup describe -d file://[your_BackupURL] --version-timestamps 

--Example Response: 
URL: file:///fdb/backupdata2/backup-2023-09-05-23-13-23.668523 
Restorable: true 
Partitioned logs: false 
Snapshot: startVersion=15923504463600 (2023/09/05.23:14:19+0800) 
endVersion=15924891885032(2023/09/05.23:37:27+0800)totalBytes=18896380483 
restorable=true expiredPct=0.00  
SnapshotBytes: 18896380483 
MinLogBeginVersion: 15923448475563 (2023/09/05.23:13:24+0800) ContiguousLogEndVersion: 15924894672515 (2023/09/05.23:37:29+0800) MaxLogEndVersion: 15924894672515 (2023/09/05.23:37:29+0800) MinRestorableVersion: 15924891885032 (2023/09/05.23:37:27+0800) MaxRestorableVersion: 15924894672514 (2023/09/05.23:37:29+0800)

